# SphinxDirective access to config._raw_config data

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I need to do something very simple:
Access the tag generated by the command line:

```
$ sphinx-build -t <tag_name>
```

Example:

```
$ sphinx-build -t Foo
```

Will create a dictionary entry in:

```
sphinx.util.docutils.SphinxDirective.config._raw_config['tags'].tags

also mirrored in:

sphinx.util.docutils.SphinxDirective.env.config._raw_config['tags'].tags
```

And `tags` will contain a dictionary with an entry:

```
'Foo': True
```

However, accessing `SphinxDirective.config._raw_config` is asking for a protected member out of scope.

**What is the correct method for accessing the Sphinx tags while processing directives?**

Comment: Wish I could help you, but I'm not a docutils hacker.

Comment: Neither am I :)

Comment: I think docutils is interesting and in a sense "the next logical step" for someone that's gotten accustomed to Sphinx. However, the published API isn't fully documented (said to be a sign it's likely to undergo future change). That leaves an interested dev with little chance other than diving into the source code. Which I imagine is overwhelming, because you'll be reverse engineering the logic. Looking at the [top docutils users on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docutils/topusers) there really isn't an actively engaged community on the subject. I guess github is where it's happening...